# ATmega8 doesn't support JMP instruction

Tags: c++, c, assembly, microcontroller, avr

Now I'm writing bootloader which starts in the middle of memory, but after it finishes I need to go to the main app, thought to try `jmp 0x00`, however my chip doesn't support `jmp`, how should I start main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well take a look into `RET` instruction. It returns to previous location, so you can try:

```
push 0x00
push 0x00
ret
```

This should work because while entering into any function you push your current location, and `RET` makes you go back.

As far as I remember ATmege8 has 16-bit address line, but if I'm not right you may need more `push 0x00`

Comment: push does not support immediates! using IJMP is twice as fast. code size should be smaller since for this variant a register have to be cleared and then the register content have to be pushed.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `RJMP`:

> Relative jump to an address within PC - 2K +1 and PC + 2K (words). In
>   the assembler, labels are used instead of relative  operands.

For example:

```
entry:
   rjmp reset
   .org 512
reset:
    rjmp foo 
   .org 3072
foo:
   rjmp entry
```

By the way, there are several other jump instructions (RJMP, IJMP, RCALL, ICALL, CALL, RET, RETI etc.) See [this relevant discussion](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=82056).

Comment: As this tagged C++ I think OP just uses inline assembly, so you should add more instructions how to use `RJMP` in that case

Comment: IJMP should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

why not simply use IJMP?

set Z to 0x00 and use IJMP. may be faster than 2xpush and ret

```
EOR R30, R30  ; clear ZL
EOR R31, R31  ; clear ZH
IJMP          ; set PC to Z
```

should be 4 cycles and 3 instruction words (6 Bytes program memory)

Comment: Agree that IJMP is slightly faster, but we shouldn't worry really much about functions that are called rarely.

Comment: @ST3 of course that does not matter but in any way it is faster and  smaller than your solution. please also note my comment on your solution